# how do generate confidence intervals/standard error of the mean for AUC?

Tags: weka

When I use a classifier like LibSVM/SMO under 10-fold cross validation, I get an output for ROC area (AUC) but there is no confidence interval given (as it was performed 10 times).  Is there a way to output this?

Answer (score 0):

With "output predictions" in "classifier evaluation option", you get predictions for each instances; with these prediction values you can compute AUC and confidence interval with other program (for exaple R or http://www.biosoft.hacettepe.edu.tr/easyROC/). I suggest to use leave one out cross validation.